# A Theorem on Main’s FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed

Theorem: Hardly anyone reads Main’s [FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq).

Proof: It contains broken English ("If you want to get a more information of the site, ..."), which would have been reported and corrected long before now if people were actually paying close attention to the FAQ in any significant number. Q.E.D.

Remark: The cited text should of course be: "If you want to get more information on the site, ..."

Comment: If people *were* actually paying close attention...

Comment: How embarrassing. Well, as they say, the cobbler's children have not shooz:)

Comment: [Muphry's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry%27s_law) (*sic*) strikes again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed. Now it reads:

> If you want to get more information about the site

Thanks for catching it.